# can i configure a product like this

Tags: image, file-upload, magento, product

I want to configure product like this,when a customer puts his order he can upload the image that he wanna see over his product

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to re-phrase your question as it cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: We need a lot more detail before this is a question that can be answered.

Comment: okay,I have some products like Mugs and Water bottles on which I will be allowing users to have their text and Images as well.So i wanna create a product in such a way that user can add his text and upload there image(from frontend in form of attributes) which he wants on his product and i can access those Image thru the database,hope the requirement is clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Custom Options.  If your product is a Simple product, just edit it, go to the Custom Options tab on the left, and you can create an option to be able to upload a file (which you can limit it to specific types of images).  You can create other custom options there too if you want text.

The thing it will not do (if you were hoping to do this) is to create a "preview" of the product with the text and/or uploaded image.